# Svelte slots & Storybook

Tags: svelte, storybook

I was wondering how to use the native svelte slots in a storybook.
For example I would want to change the slot:
`Button.svelte`:

```html
<div role="button"><slot>Button</slot></div>
```

and also how would you do something like:
`Button2.svelte`:

```html
<div role="button"><slot>Button</slot><slot name="after">After Content</slot></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was making a separate component like so:

`./Button.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import Button from "../../lib/components/Button.svelte";

  export let slot = "Button";
</script>

<Button>{@html slot}</Button>
```

and leaving my `$lib/components/Button.svelte` untouched.